# VBA- Concatenate Cells with If function

Tags: excel, if-statement, concatenation, vba

I have a code that returns all the data I want from a query. The problem is that the csv format separates the data, even account names with commas in them. For each row, column A is the account name followed by 11 blocks of integer data (making a total of 12 cells used per row). Fortunately, for the accounts that have commas, the result is only one additional cell (making a total of 13 cells used per row).

I need an IF-THEN formula that will concatenate Column A & Column B if there are 13 used cells in that row, otherwise leaving things alone. Being new to VBA concatenate is giving me huge problems.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just from a term point of view, Excel Formulas and Excel VBA are not the same thing.

In fact, there are a lot of people on here that are formula pros that know nothing about VBA and visa versa.

That being said, you could use something like:

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(C1:N1)=0,A1&" "&B1,A1)
```

Of course, assuming your data looks like this:

[image]

It would be easier to use:

```
=IF(N1="",A1,A1&" "&B1)
```

Concatenating in Excel formulas and VBA is pretty simple.

Simply separate the strings you wish to concatenate with an amperstand `&`

If I want to concatenate A1 and B1, I can use `=A1&B1` as shown in the formula.

If I want to add a space, or even a word, I can just add it between them as a string:

`=A1&" is way cooler than "&B1`

**Edit:**

VBA:

```
Sub ConcatenateCells()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim FixRange As Range, c As Range
Set FixRange = Range("A1:A" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
For Each c In FixRange
    If InStr(c, ",") > 0 Then c = c & c.Offset(0, 1)
    'You could also add a space between the two using c = c & " " & c.Offset(0, 1)
Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I don't know if you want to scoot the data over after you have concatenated the values, but if you do, you can use this:

```
Sub ConcatenateAndScootCells()
Dim FixRange As Range, c As Range
Set FixRange = Range("A1:A" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
For Each c In FixRange
    If InStr(c, ",") > 0 Then
        c = c & c.Offset(0, 1)
        c.Offset(0, 1).Delete xlToLeft
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Still assuming I got your data format right, here is what the before and after looks like:

[image: Before]

[image: After]

**Final Edit:**

If you absolutely insist on counting the number of used rows instead of simply looking for a coma in column A, then use this:

```
Sub ConcatenateAndScootCells()
Dim FixRange As Range, c As Range
Set FixRange = Range("A1:A" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
For Each c In FixRange
    If Cells(c.row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column = 13 Then
        c = c & " " & c.Offset(0, 1)
        c.Offset(0, 1).Delete xlToLeft
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Pardon the terminology, I'm working on a VBA code to correct the problem above not a formula approach. Your example was spot on, but since I'm looking for code to correct things, can I still use the same concatenate A1&B1 you listed above?

Comment: Yes. You can use `Cells(1, 1) & Cells(1, 2)` or `Range("A1") & Range("B1")`

Comment: I edited the answer with VBA code to do this. Instead of counting the cells to the right of it, I simply searched for a coma. If you wanted to count the cells to the right, you could do that as well.

Comment: So here's what I'm entering in code:

Countit = Sheets("Income").UsedRange.Rows(1).Columns.Count
            If Countit = 13 Then
            Cells (1,1) & Cells (1,2)
            End If

This doesn't seem to be working. The 'Countit' variable is set 'As String'. What am I entering wrong?

Comment: I already answered your question with VBA code. Please see my edit. That's how you do what you're trying to do. Also, please confirm that I have your data setup right because you still haven't done so.

Comment: See my final edit. The syntax is (assuming active sheet) `Cells(c.row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column = 13`